# Wifi suddenly stopped working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I worked on my laptop (Lnovo G510) using wired connection for few hours and after this time I turned off my laptop. When I came home, I wanted to use wireless connection and there problem appeared. When I turned on laptop there is no wifi option to choose in connection menu and I have no idea why. Now I'm using wired connection but it isn't comfortable way. I checked drivers and there are still installed. I need yuor help :)

```
rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
```

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list` and `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok, added

Comment: `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
google-chrome.list    nodesource.list
mongodb-org-3.0.list  webupd8team-sublime-text-2-trusty.list`

Answer (score 1):

The wireless driver is not installed. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

The driver does not build for the currently installed kernel.

There may be a bug, or it did not fully install with headers.

Run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

this should fix problem with your headers.

As an alternative you can upgrade your kernel to 3.19 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot. It can solve these issues.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. After this command:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.`

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` andlook for errors. And what is your kernel version? `uname -r` ?

Comment: Maybe this part can be interesting:
`Building only for 3.16.0-40-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-40-generic
`

Comment: #2 What is your kernel version?

Comment: 3.16.0-40-generic

Comment: This is wrong. Disable "proposed" in "Software & Updates", boot with previous standard kernel 3.16.0-39 and remove 3.16.0-40 image and headers.

Comment: But it looks like even in "proposed" there is no 3.16.0-40. Where did you get that kernel? Some ppa? Please give output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Post it to your question.

Comment: I don't know how to do things you wrote.  I didn't change my kernel purposely.  I want to say thank you for your engagement.

Comment: You have either some other distro installed, not Ubuntu, or installed kernel from somewhere.

Comment: Opps sry. It really has been upgraded to 3.16.0-40. Either way boot with a previous kernel and wifi will work.

Comment: Thank you for your help - it works and I posted an answer to say precisely how to resolve this problem.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04. My wireless connection disappeared after I did `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve problem I've installed headers to my kernel, by typing `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and then I've reinstalled drivers by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` and it works perfectly. @Pilot6 thank you for you help.

Comment: It is strange that your headers did not install.

Comment: You probably upgraded kernel some time in a wrong way. Run `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic`. This will install meta package and your headers will be always up to date.